# Chrome & Safari not Caching Big Video

Tags: google-chrome, caching, safari, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm hosting a site that serves an HTML video. My server's video response includes the header `cache-control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable`. Everything works on Firefox, but on Chrome and Safari I am not seeing the caching results that I expect.

My JavaScript (Angular) seeks the video to a random location at random time intervals. There are two related, but distinct, problems I'm facing:

1. Chrome and Safari request a video range **every time** that the video seeks, even if it's already requested that range. That means that if I leave the browser open, it will **never stop making requests**.
2. Chrome and Safari don't cache the video between page loads.

I suspected that the problem lies in the size of the video (170 MB), so I substituted it with a smaller video (9 MB) for testing purposes. The shorter video experiences none of the problems that the longer video does:

1. If the video is not cached. Chrome and Safari make only **one** request. They do not make new requests for every seek.
2. After the first request, Chrome and Safari cache the video for new video requests.

The request/response headers are the same for the two videos, and all the responses have `206` statuses. The only significant difference I can find is that the smaller video usually takes only 1 request to download, whereas the bigger video takes multiple.

Why am I unable to cache the bigger video? How do I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you're sending `206` status code for partial content along with `age header`, but that's not all.

**Approach 1**

You have to send `Content-Range` headers which can signify the range of the content that is being downloaded for the media to help browser. Also, there is a cache limit of the browser which automatically prune old/stale content on coming up of fresh content. You can read thoroughly [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.5.3),

**Approach 2**

Also, if the header strategy doesn't work, you can always try `service-worker` caching and build your own cache bucket and cache strategy for specific media content, you can read more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies).

> I hope while testing caching, you're not "Disabling Cache" in
> Dev-tools and also verify the correct request and response headers
> from server logs instead of browser for validating caching.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: The browser automatically sends Content-Range headers when requesting the video. I looked into using service-workers, but its a bit more complicated a solution than I'm looking for, and I'd like to understand the problem instead of finding a workaround.